# What is an alternative for using lists as keys for dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a chess game. The board is stored in a 2d list. The game also has an ai running the minimax algorithm. I want to speed up the ai by adding the score for a particular board state (which is a 2d list) to a dictionary (checked_states_max for the maximizer and checked_states_min for the minimizer). How could I do this since, in python, lists cannot be used as dictionary keys because they are mutable? I fear that converting it all to a tuple would be inefficient.

Comment: Have you verifiably *checked* that conversion to tuples is inefficient / not performant for your use case? If you provide a [mcve] and can demonstrate this is your bottleneck, we can look at alternatives.

Comment: You can convert your board to a single vector (list of tuple), which might be practical for ai.

Comment: Converting to tuple would be the standard approach

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak why would you convert to a list of tuples? It could just be a nested list and then, at least, it supports reassingment.

Comment: @roganjosh he's already using a nested list, but needs something hashable he can use as a dictionary key to memoize some results.

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm reading the list of tuples/nested lists as a replacement to a dictionary. I need to re-read.

Comment: sorry for a typo - it should read _list **or** tuple_

Comment: Just a `dict_key = tuple(list)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

[Zobrist hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing) is what you're looking for.

Implement a hash function which takes the game state (note, not just the current board since castling and en passant may not be valid depending on previous moves) and returns a single integer.